# How to use a criteria range with calculated values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel has the function `AVERAGEIFS` that lets one define criteria ranges in order to only include a cell in the average calculation if another cell holds a specific value, e.g. calculate the average of values in A1 through A10 if the cells next to them (B1 through B10) hold the value 1:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A10;B1:B10;1)
```

I'm actually using more criteria but let's keep it simple. Now, my B values hold "too precise" values which is why I want to `FLOOR` them. I have so far created a column C which simply does that.

```
=FLOOR(B1)
```

My formular thus changes to:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A10;C1:C10;1)
```

This works. The problem is that I cannot always change the input sheet (nor do I want to). Therefore, I'm looking for a way to say

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A10;FLOOR(B1:B10);1)
```

But that, of course, does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the same result with `SUMPRODUCT()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FLOOR(B1:B10,1)=1)*(A1:A10))/SUMPRODUCT(--(FLOOR(B1:B10,1)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I expected and I like the solution, thanks! I had to fiddle around a bit as I also used wildcards but I was able to work around it with a `--ISNUMBER(FIND("pattern",area))` approach.

Comment: @jhr  Good job !!